# launchctl OS X Perl Global Daemon Variable

Tags: perl, osx-yosemite, launchd

I have a script that uses `#!/usr/bin/env perl`. I'm wondering how to set the env variable for launchctl so my script will use 5.20.1 (all user accounts are using 5.20.1) as currently is set at 5.18.

This might be partially caused from the upgrade from OS X Mavericks to OS X Yosemite.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your `PATH` variable so that the path to the perl.exe that you want to use appears first

Answer (score 0):

```
$ENV{'PATH'} = '/some/new/path';
```

Comment: Please consider adding some more detail to the answer. :)

Comment: I don't exactly understand..... My perl script is inside a .sh file that is run as a global daemon/launchctl.